# Get selected item value from Bootstrap DropDown with specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am "creating" my own "ComboBox" using **`Bootstrap 3`** and *JavaScript*. [**`Here is the JSFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/kcpma/17/) for what I have so far:

### **HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group">                                            
    <input type="TextBox" ID="datebox" Class="form-control"></input>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="demolist" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### **JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
    $('#datebox').val($(this).html());
});
```

This approach works great untill I want to repeat this "ComboBox" several times on the page. The issue is with the JQuery function looking for ANY/ALL `'.dropdown-menu li a'`.

**How can I change my JQuery to look *only* for UL with ID *demolist* and get its *selected* value?**

I have tried the following without success:

I tried `'#demolist .dropdown-menu li a'` but that will not fire the function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#demolist .dropdown-menu li a', function() {
    $('#datebox').val($(this).html());
});
```

I tried calling the Click of **#demolist** but `#datebox` gets the HTML of ALL list item of #demolist and not the *selected* innerHTML of item:

```
$('#demolist').on('click', function(){
    $('#datebox').val($(this).html());
});
```

### UPDATE:

The working solutions are:

```
$('#demolist li a').on('click', function(){
    $('#datebox').val($(this).html());
});
```

**OR**

```
$('#demolist li').on('click', function(){
    $('#datebox').val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: If you gave a '-1', you should confront my question and tell me why?

Comment: No idea, +1 i see no problem with the question

Comment: See the answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620741/get-selected-item-value-from-bootstrap-dropdown-with-specific-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620741/get-selected-item-value-from-bootstrap-dropdown-with-specific-id)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$('#demolist li').on('click', function(){
    $('#datebox').val($(this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kcpma/18/

Comment: I have tried this before also, but it didnt work for me. The issue is how to get the SELECTD item, not ALL items.

Comment: Good catch! The working code would be #demolist li a

Comment: This returns `value="[object Object]"` for me.

Answer (score 7):

Design code using Bootstrap

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="demolist">
  <a class="dropdown-item" h ref="#">Cricket</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">UFC</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Football</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Basketball</a>
</div>
```

- jquery Code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#demolist a').on('click', function () {
      var txt= ($(this).text());
      alert("Your Favourite Sports is "+txt);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector would be `#demolist.dropdown-menu li a` note no space between id and class.
However i would suggest a more generic approach:

```
<div class="input-group">                                            
    <input type="TextBox" Class="form-control datebox"></input>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.datebox').val($(this).html());
});
```

by using a class rather than id, and using  `parent().find()`, you can have as many of these on a page as you like, with no duplicated js

Comment: You are correct, however I am interested in getting the selected value of a specific LIST. Your approach only updates ANY INPPUT with .datebox class.

Comment: Well as i said `#demolist.dropdown-menu li a` will do what you want. However my suggested code updates the **specific** input that is next to the clicked link (technically the input that is a sibling of the ul), so you can have 10 of these code blocks on a page and each one updates its own input

Comment: Yes but the issue is: ANY item that has class **.dropdown-menu li a** is going to trigger the *CLICK* function. I only wanted to trigger the function if and when a specific UL with a list of items gets clicked. Thanks for your help! I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Ah Ok, I was under the impression you wanted to create a reusable control without having to wire up specific click handlers for each one. My mistake, glad you found a solution

Answer (score 1):

Did you just try

```
$('#datebox li a').on('click', function(){
    //$('#datebox').val($(this).text());
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

It works for me :)

Comment: Yohann, please add more details regarding how did you test it, maybe steps and versions you are using to help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to modify your jQuery code a bit to `'#demolist li a'` so it specifically selects the text that is in the link rather than the text that is in the li element. That would allow you to have a sub-menu without causing issues. Also since your are specifically selecting the a tag you can access it with `$(this).text();`.

```
$('#datebox li a').on('click', function(){
    //$('#datebox').val($(this).text());
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works GReat.

Category Question
    
    
    Apple
    Banana
    Cherry

```
<input type="text" name="cat_q" id="cat_q">  

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_cat div a").click(function(){
       alert($(this).text());

    });
});
```

Comment: <div class="dropdown" id="btn_cat">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data- 
    toggle="dropdown">
    Category Question
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="cat_q" id="cat_q">

Comment: Maybe this comment should added to the answer as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
<input type="TextBox" ID="yearBox" border="0" disabled>

$('#yearSelected li').on('click', function(){
                $('#yearBox').val($(this).text());
            });



<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> <span>Academic Years</span> <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <ul class="menu" id="yearSelected">
                <li><a href="#">2014-2015</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2015-2016</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2016-2017</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2017-2018</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

its work for me