# Item not selected in Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, drop-down-menu

Using bootstrap, I am selecting dropdown menu but it's not working and selected item is not appearing on top of the list.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Select Business type <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">small</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">medium</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">large</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap to create dropdown

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap

Comment: is bootstrap css/js and jquery loaded??

Comment: it is now @Durga

Comment: @SergChernata add jquery also

Comment: Please help angular js code jquery problem with some time.

Comment: What you really want is the selected option to appear on top of the menu?¿

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected item value from Bootstrap DropDown with specific ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620741/get-selected-item-value-from-bootstrap-dropdown-with-specific-id)

Comment: Yes now not appear on top of the menu

Comment: are you using angularJs too

Answer (score 1):

You will need some JavaScript to store the text value of the selected option in the button.

As you are already using jQuery you can bind to the click event of the list items and then copy the text of the item to the text value of the button.

However, you also have to preserve the little caret `<span class="caret"></span>` so you can either make a template or just copy it and append it after the text has been changed.

In the below example I went with the find/append option.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function() {
  var $dropdown = $('.dropdown-toggle');
  var text = $(this).text();
  var $span = $dropdown.find('span');
  
  $dropdown.text(text).append($span);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Select Business type <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">small</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">medium</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">large</a></li>
  </ul>
```

If you want to get fancier you could store the "template" in a variable and re-use it, similar to this:

```js
var dropdownTextTemplate = '{0} <span class="caret"></span>'

$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function() {
  var $dropdown = $('.dropdown-toggle');
  var text = $(this).text();
  var $span = $dropdown.find('span');
  
  $dropdown.html(dropdownTextTemplate.replace('{0}', text));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Select Business type <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">small</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">medium</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">large</a></li>
  </ul>
```